# Best XML parser for C

Tags: c, xml, parsing

We have to add a new interface to our existing C application. The new interface system requests to our C application and responses to interface will be XML files. We need find a way to read and write XML files. It seems there are many mapping tools available for Java and C++. I did not find anyone for C.

Please let me know if there is anyone suitable for C. We will be okay if it's commercial API as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most widely used is libxml2.  You can take a look [here](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I did anything in anger with XML in C but at the time the best offering was the Gnome XML library - libxml from [www.xmlsoft.org](http://www.xmlsoft.org).

Should be worth a look.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) for some time now, which is great if you need a very fast streaming parser for C.  I believe there are DOM and SAX extentions if you need them.

Comment: Wil Expat support Unix environment

Comment: Expat is very simple, with full source, and will support pretty much any C environment, including Windows Unix, Mac, BEOS and Amiga from what I can see in the header files.